# Login Fragment returning two duplicate screens of new activity?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-login

**UPDATED FOUND SOLUTION**

My situation is simple.

I have a `MainActivity` on which a fragment is created called `FacebookLoginFragment`.

The `FacebookLoginFragment` creates a `LoginButton` from which the user can login into facebook with. After the user logs in, they are directed to a profile page which is created from the fetched data called `ProfileActivity`.

I've tested the app myself and created several logs throughout the process to see if the login is successful, and yes I am able to fetch the userId correctly.

The problem is that when the user clicks "Log in with Facebook" they are directed back to `MainActivity` which should only be shown once, and then redirected to `ProfileActivity` and two `RelativeLayouts` of `ProfileActivity` are shown. I know this because when I hit the back button on the android it redirects me to a duplicate of `ProfileActivity` from `ProfileActivity`

I can't seem to figure out what the problem here is, I'm guessing it has something to do with the Intent I've declared in `onCompleted`. Here is my `onCompleted` method:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null){
                    Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject() + " " + user.getLocation());
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("Fb_id", user.getId());
                    i.putExtra("Fb_first_name", user.getFirstName());
                    i.putExtra("Fb_last_name", user.getLastName());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();  
    } else if (state.isClosed()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

I'm posting my activities as a reference.

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FacebookLoginFragment mainFragment;

private ImageView splashLogo;
protected Animation anim;


@Override
/*
 * called when activity is first created, only once
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        //Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new FacebookLoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        //Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (FacebookLoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

    splashLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoFixed);
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus)
        splashLogo.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my `FacebookLoginFragment`:

```
public class FacebookLoginFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private final List<String> permissions;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        //Pass in onSessionStateChange listener
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null){
        if (savedInstanceState != null){ //Restore session 
            session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, callback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null){
            session = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
        }
    }

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

    return view;
}

public FacebookLoginFragment() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_location");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null){
                    Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject() + " " + user.getLocation());
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class); //getActivity() returns the activity the Fragment is associated with
                    i.putExtra("Fb_id", user.getId());
                    i.putExtra("Fb_first_name", user.getFirstName());
                    i.putExtra("Fb_last_name", user.getLastName()); 
                    startActivity(i);
                    }   
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (state.isClosed()){
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

/*
 * For some reason it keeps telling me to remove @Override
 */
public void onDestory(){
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Here is my `ProfileActivity`:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

protected ProfilePictureView profilePicture;

private TextView userInfoTextView;
private String userId;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_facebook);

    Intent i = getIntent(); //Grab the intent from previous activity
    userId = i.getStringExtra("Fb_id");

    profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    profilePicture.setProfileId(userId);

    userInfoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following methods were added to the `MainActivity` class.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
}
```

Me being new to android development I wasn't aware of the profound implications of the lifecycle methods.

In the `FacebookLoginFragment` class

The following code was moved to `onCreate()`

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.i(TAG, "Session grabbed");
    if (session == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "session is null");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { // Restore session
            session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, callback,
                    savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(TAG, "savedInstanceState not null, session restored");
        }
        if (session == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "session set to new Session(getActivity())");
            session = new Session(getActivity()); // If no session is
                                                    // present create new
                                                    // session
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        Log.i(TAG, "Session.setActiveSession(session)");
    }
```

The following code was removed:

```
if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
    }
```

The following code was added right before `startActivity()` inside the `onCompleted()` method inside `onSessionStatechange`

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The above code clears out the previous screens so that when user logs in via facebook they cannot hit `back` and go back to the login page

The following method was added to the `FacebookLoginFragment` class to save the bundle because bundle kept returning null whenever I went to home and back to app:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.i(TAG, "Session saved 239");
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}
```

**THE PROBLEM(S)**:

- onSessionStateChange() was being called twice
- previous activities were not clearing

**Explanation**

- It is my belief that because the bundle was not being saved or restored the method `onSessionStateChange` was being called twice and because there was an `Intent` present in `onSessionStateChange` you see duplicate activities.

If anyone sees anything wrong with this please let me know.

**Things I am still trying to fix**

- The app skips a lot of frames when run, I am still looking into it

***Closing Note***

- I hope this helps someone out, I scratched my head at this and pulled my hair for more than a few days.